# How to call/find a reference for windows form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

            using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (skeletonFrame != null)
                {
                    skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
                }
                if (skeletons.Length != 0)
                {
                    foreach (Skeleton skel in skeletons)
                    {
                        if (skel.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                        {
                            this.tracked(skel);
                            this.trackedLeft(skel);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

i can not seems to find `"SkeletonArrayLength"` and `"SkeletonTrackingState"` anywhere, does the problem lies with reference or do i need a set of coding for this?

Comment: SkeletonFrame  does not contain a property called SkeletonArrayLength and SkeletonTrackingState is not referenced. Make sure you are adding all the correct 'using' statements in your class.

Comment: any idea on which 'using' statement is needed or should i change my codes entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the referene of Microsoft.Kinect (in microsoft.kinect.dll) and then add the namespace Microsoft.Kinect into your project .
May be this Linq could help you ::
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.skeletonframe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

About the SkeletonArrayLength error..

SkeletonFrame class doesn't have a property called "SkeletonArrayLength".

If can view the source code of the SkeletonFrame class then it should look like this..

```
public class SkeletonFrame
{
    ...
    // other fields/properties
    public int SkeletonArrayLength { get; set; }
    // methods
}
```

and for the SkeletonTrackingState, click the code with an error on visual studio and press **Ctrl key + '.' key**. (It's a shortcut to show you a menu of what you can do on a particular line of code)

if there is no "add using xxx" suggestion then there is no way to find out where the SkeletonTrackingState class or enum resides.

Comment: should this be added into the source code or is it suppose to be there? If must be added, how do i get there?

Comment: You should not modify the source code if you are not its author. I've checked avaneesh's link and it seems to fit the class you are trying to access. Try adding reference to Microsoft.Kinect. Also, it is best if you describe your scenario when asking questions for example if the code you posted is from a tutorial or existing project that you want to modify so others can help you.

Comment: yeah man i added the (microsoft.kinect.dll) still nothing is solved.